# PHP MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have 3 MySQL tables, one filed with the users information, one with their course history and the last one filled with their reward history.

I am attempting to create a "rewards" program if you will, using these two databases and a PHP script. As far as the reward requirements, I have 2 arrays setup for the two types of rewards:

```
//Pen Reward with course A & B required
$pen=array("a","b")

//Cup Reward with course B & C required
$cup=array("b","c")
```

I can't figure out how to first query for all user IDs, then go through their history. If they match the requirements set above, then to update the reward table to 1 (to show that they received the award)

**UsersDB**

```
userid    name
----------------
1         bill
2         john
3         steve
```

**HistoryDB**

```
userid    courseid
------------------
1         a
1         b
2         b
3         a
3         c
```

**RewardHistoryDB**

```
userid    pen    cup  
---------------------
1         0      0
2         0      0
3         0      0
```

Ideally it after the PHP script runs, it would update the RewardHistoryDB to reflect that user 1 received a pen, and user 3 received a cup.(the DB would look like this:)

**RewardHistoryDB** (after)

```
userid    pen    cup  
---------------------
1         1      0
2         0      0
3         0      1
```

Here is the PHP code I am using right now (not complete):

```
$userid=array();
$i=0;

//Find All users
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT userid FROM usersdb")
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $universityid[$i]=$row['universityid'];
    $i++;
}

//Find History
$courseid=array();
foreach ($userid as $userid1){
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT courseid FROM historydb WHERE userid='".$userid1."'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $courseid[]=$row;
    }
}

//Update Reward DB
//Don't even know where to start...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
If you have any questions, please let me know.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: So what is not working?

Comment: I can query the UserIDs and history fine, but I just don't know how to combine them, a comb through to verify if they met the requirements (stored in $pen or $cup)...sorry post wasn't clear, I'll update it

Comment: is there a reason you need to do this in PHP and not in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a96b/1/0

You can do this just as queries and without doing any logic in PHP

```
update RewardHistoryDB
   set Pen = 1 
   where UserID in ( 
         select  UserID 
         from    HistoryDB 
         where   CourseID in ('A','B')
         group   by UserID
         having  count(UserID)=2);


update RewardHistoryDB
   set Cup = 1 
   where UserID in ( 
         select  UserID 
         from    HistoryDB 
         where   CourseID in ('B','C')
         group   by UserID
         having  count(UserID)=2);
```

---

Or you can even do it in one, large statement...

```
update RewardHistoryDB   

      left outer join (
            select  UserID as Pens_UserID
            from    HistoryDB 
            where   CourseID in ('A','B')
            group   by UserID
            having  count(UserID)=2 ) as Pens
         on RewardHistoryDB.UserID = Pens.Pens_UserID 

      left outer join (
            select  UserID as Cups_UserID
            from    HistoryDB 
            where   CourseID in ('B','C')
            group   by UserID
            having  count(UserID)=2 ) as Cups
         on RewardHistoryDB.UserID = Cups.Cups_UserID 

set Pen = case when Pens.Pens_UserID is not null then 1 else 0 end,
    Cup = case when Cups.Cups_UserID is not null then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: that works perfectly. thank you. i feel so dumb
i thought i had to do the logic in PHP
didnt realize that SQL could handle this

thanks again!